# In NoSQL databases like MongoDB and Cassandra, what is the proper way to model a resource that can contain an array of the same type of attribute?

Tags: database, mongodb, cassandra, data-modeling

For instance, let's say I am trying to design a model for a database that stores Instagram posts and that a single post can have multiple images. Let's say I'm storing images in S3. My question is how would I tie the images and the posts together?

In a standard relational Database I would probably create a separate table for images and store the foreign key of the Instagram post and the path to the image in S3. Then when I am retrieving the post, I would join on this images table.

In a NoSQL DB like MongoDB or Cassandra, my understanding is that it is better to avoid joins for the sake of latency. So would I store an array of image paths directly in my posts table?

Comment: I suggest to separate the question into separate questions for Cassandra and MongoDB as they are different. For example, Cassandra doesn't support joins at all. 
There is already an issue with the question that the accepted answer only covers MongoDB and not Cassandra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mongodb case, My approach would be like this:

```
{
  "name":"post1",
  "content":"post1 content",
  "images":[
    "https://example.com/img1.jpg",
    "https://example.com/img2.jpg"
  ]
}
```

Yes, it's better to embed than to link other documents, unless you have a good reason to it.

even in case you need to fetch all images, you can query the db, and *project* the result to match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a Cassandra answer:

Similarly to the MongoDB solution, Cassandra allows you to embed data like this in collections.  In this case, a `LIST` would be a good option.

Also, you'll want to model your data by how you'll query it.  While having a post id is useful, it's probably something with a low level of query usage.  More likely, queries for post-like data are by date and/or time, so keying on that will be important.

Take all that into consideration, and the resulting Cassandra table should look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.posts_by_month (
    month int,
    posttime timestamp,
    id uuid,
    content text,
    images list<text>,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (month, posttime, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (posttime DESC, id ASC);
```

Note that month may or may not be a good value for your use case.  Depending on how many posts are written in a given month, a smaller "time bucket" may be required.

Then you could query posts within the last month, like this:

```
SELECT post_time,name,content,images FROM posts_by_month
WHERE month=202111
AND posttime > '2021-11-01 09:00';

  posttime                        | name  | content       | images
 ---------------------------------+-------+---------------+--------------------------
  2021-11-01 09:19:00.000000+0000 | post1 | post1 content | ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg']

(1 rows)
```